# using javascript to code the preorder traversal

Tags: javascript, algorithm, preorder

```
var preorderTraversal = function(root) {
    var array = [];
    if(!(root == null)){
       array.push(root.val) ;
        preorderTraversal(root.left);
        preorderTraversal(root.right);
    }
    return array;
};
```

The code failed in testing when the test case is [1,2], I only output [1], how to fix it?

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that you're creating a new, separate array in each recursive call (and then discarding it, since you don't do anything with what the recursive calls return).

An alternative approach is to pass in an "accumulator" array acc, and pass it to every recursive call, so that all elements get added to a single array:

```
var preorderTraversal = function(root, acc = []) {
   if(!!root){
      acc.push(root.val);
      if (root.left) preorderTraversal(root.left, acc);
      if (root.right) preorderTraversal(root.right, acc);
   }
   return acc;
};
```

You might also be interested in traversing `pre-ordered BST` iteratively, instead of recursively:

```
var preorderTraversal = function(root) {
   /**
    * Algorithm:
    * 1. Create an empty stack [];
    * 2. Do while stack is not empty:
    * 2.1. Pop an item from stack and add it to the 'result' array.
    * 2.2. Push 'right child' of popped item to stack.
    * 2.3. Push 'left child' of popped item to stack.
   */
   if (root == null) {
     return [];
   }

   const stack = [];
   const result = [];

   stack.push(root);

   while(stack.length > 0) {
     let current = stack.pop();
     result.push(current.val);

     if (current.right) stack.push(current.right);
     if (current.left) stack.push(current.left);
   }

   return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

array is a local variable then:

1. you put 1 on array with push
2. recursively go to others sides when you create again array = []
3. push 2
4. when you return to your top of recursion stack array still have only 1

maybe is better if you can send array as argument, and use returned array for modify the local one

Answer (score 0):

You will need a helper function for inline printing for js; this helper function should call your actual `preorder` function.

Inside of your `preorder` function, you need to always keep updating the string "passed" (I explain the "" afterwards). If current node is empty, you should return the current string you have at the moment, otherwise it would wipe it off.

```js
function doPreOrder(root, str) {
  if(!root) {
    return str;
  }
  if(!str) {
    str = "";
  }
  if(root) {
    str += root.val + ' ';
    str = doPreOrder(root.left, str);
    str = doPreOrder(root.right, str);
  }
  return str;
}

function preOrder(root) {
  var x = doPreOrder(root);
  console.log(x);
}
```

As you can see, we first need to use the function, and only pass root. We're passing an undefined var to it, and it will be the only time we will enter the `str = ""` code, and then from that point on, the `str` will update for each new data. At the end, you just console log that var.